# Split data frame by class regarding to OID

Tags: r, dataframe, split, dplyr

I try to split dataframe by 50% by class. However, I do not want to split fields with the same OID (object identifier). I would like the fields with the same OID to be in the same set.

```
    #Data frame:
   "b1""b2""b3""CLASS"   "OID"
    110 134 119 "tree"      1
    112 133 118 "tree"      1
    105 125 110 "tree"      2
    112 132 117 "tree"      2
    109 125 115 "meadow"    6
    93  110 101 "meadow"    6
    86  106 95  "meadow"    7
    105 136 116 "meadow"    7
    102 128 111 "meadow"    8
    108 129 115 "meadow"    8
    113 134 119 "meadow"    8
```

Expected data:

```
#Expected:
    "b1""b2""b3""CLASS"   "OID"
    110 134 119 "tree"      1
    112 133 118 "tree"      1
    109 125 115 "meadow"    6
    93  110 101 "meadow"    6
    86  106 95  "meadow"    7
    105 136 116 "meadow"    7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This selects the top half of rows in each group, plus any rows which have the same OID as the rows in that top half.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(CLASS) %>% 
  filter(OID %in% head(OID, n() %/% 2)) %>% 
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      b1    b2    b3 CLASS    OID
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <int>
# 1   110   134   119 tree       1
# 2   112   133   118 tree       1
# 3   109   125   115 meadow     6
# 4    93   110   101 meadow     6
# 5    86   106    95 meadow     7
# 6   105   136   116 meadow     7
```

If your real data is arranged by OID like this example, you could also use `top_frac`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(CLASS) %>% 
  top_frac(.5, -OID)

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      b1    b2    b3 CLASS    OID
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <int>
# 1   110   134   119 tree       1
# 2   112   133   118 tree       1
# 3   109   125   115 meadow     6
# 4    93   110   101 meadow     6
# 5    86   106    95 meadow     7
# 6   105   136   116 meadow     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
df = structure(list(b1 = c(110L, 112L, 105L, 112L, 109L, 93L, 86L, 
105L, 102L, 108L, 113L), b2 = c(134L, 133L, 125L, 132L, 125L, 
110L, 106L, 136L, 128L, 129L, 134L), b3 = c(119L, 118L, 110L, 
117L, 115L, 101L, 95L, 116L, 111L, 115L, 119L), CLASS = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("meadow", 
"tree"), class = "factor"), OID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

First create a function to take 1/2 according to OID

```
func = function(x){
x[x$OID %in% x$OID[1:round(nrow(x)/2)],]
}
```

We randomize the way the OID are sorted

```
df$OID = factor(df$OID,levels=sample(unique(df$OID)))
df = df[order(df$OID),]
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$CLASS,func))
```

This will ensure you get random ~ 50% everytime, with complete OID

Comment: Could this function be changed to divide the frame in half and get two data frames(50:50) divided according to this method?

Comment: @Nicolas, You provide a row ID, and then retrieve from the original data.frame, those not included in this function?